# echo text with new line in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to append text to a file. So I wrote in bash

```
echo text >> file.conf
```

However it doesn't leave a new line. So I can only do this once. How do I add a new line?

Comment: What do you mean? An **extra** newline? `echo` adds a newline by default.

Comment: `echo` by default does leave a newline - do you need it to leave two? Also, if you're running this on a linux system and opening the file on a windows or mac system, make sure your editor supports *nix newlines, or it'll appear all on one line even though it's on multiple lines.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

option 1:

```
% echo -e "text\n" >> file.conf
```

option 2:

```
% ( echo text ; echo "" ) >> file.conf
```

option 3:

```
% echo text >> file.conf
% echo ""  >> file.conf
```

Comment: You can drop the empty argument (`echo ""` => `echo`). Also, option 4: `echo $'text\n'`, which is useful for any command as the `$''` is interpreted by bash.

Answer (score 13):

I think the proper answer should be that your command

> echo text >> file.conf

does add an extra line, but **after** the new text, not before.

I guess that you want to add an extra line before that text, probably because your initial file doesn't end in a new line. In that case you could use

> echo -e "\ntext" >> file.conf

instead, as the `-e` option allows you to use the new line `\n` character.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to akira's response

Option 4:

use `ctrl-v ctrl-m` key combos twice to insert two newline control character in the terminal. Ctrl-v lets you insert control characters into the terminal. You could use the enter or return key instead of the ctrol-m if you like. It inserts the same thing.

This ends up looking like `echo text^M^M >> file.conf`

Comment: If you need linefeeds instead of carriage returns (linux/unix), try `echo "text^J^J" >> file.conf` Typing ^J might actually insert a literal newline, just make sure to put the quotes and it'll be good.